# How to render x-axis labels in Highcharts without the decimal points?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I need to display my x-axis label as a whole number with percentage without the decimal and a zero before it. I am already using `allowDecimals: false` but that's not helping it looks like. How can I fix this?

`0.10%` should render as `10%` and etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/p01xvw2z/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        height: 550
      },
      title: {
        text: 'GME: Absolute Daily Return vs. % of Outstanding Shares Hedged, January 2021',
        align: 'left',
        style: {
          fontSize: '20px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Data source: OPERA and Bloomberg',
        align: 'left'
      },
      credits: { enabled: false },
      xAxis: {
        title: { text: '% of Outstanding Shares Needed for Hedging' },
        // labels: {
        //   formatter: function () {
        //     return this.value.toFixed(2) + '%'
        //   }
        // },
        labels: {
          format: '{value:,.2f}%'
        },
        min: -0.01,
        max: 0.6,
        tickInterval: 0.1,
        allowDecimals: false
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Absolute % Change in Price' },
        min: -0.01,
        tickInterval: 0.5,
        labels: {
          formatter: function () {
            return this.value.toFixed(1)
          }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
          type: 'line',
          name: '',
          color: "#f79646",
          data: [[0, -.1489], [0.5, 0.7003]],
          marker: {
              enabled: false
          },
          states: {
              hover: {
                  lineWidth: 0
              }
          },
          enableMouseTracking: false
      }, {
          type: 'scatter',
          marker: {
            symbol: 'circle',
            fillColor: '#00429d',
            radius: 3
          },
          name: 'Observations',
          color: '#000',
          data: [
            [0.05, 0.08],
            [0.05, 0.00],
            [0.08, 0.05],
            [0.08, 0.01],
            [0.05, 0.02],
            [0.13, 0.12],
            [0.11, 0.00],
            [0.35, 0.57],
            [0.42, 0.27],
            [0.38, 0.11],
            [0.22, 0.10],
            [0.21, 0.00],
            [0.26, 0.09],
            [0.48, 0.51],
            [0.34, 0.18],
            [0.44, 0.92],
            [0.43, 1.34],
            [0.34, 0.44],
            [0.42, 0.67]
          ],
          tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
          }
      }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
     labels: {
       formatter: function () {
         return this.value * 100 + '%';
       }
     },
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!